# Вывод данных из таблицы в базу mysql

Tags: mysql, odbc

Есть программа- источник данных, в которой лежат нужные таблицы.
Данные в этих таблицах обновляются часто(несколько раз в минуту).
Я пытаюсь разобраться, каким образом можно настроить выгрузку в реальном времени этих данных (через ODBC) в базу. Т.е. чтобы при появлении новой записи в таблице-источнике она сразу же появлялась в базе mysql без ручного нажимания кнопок обновления таблицы.
Возможно эта возможность как-то заложена по умолчанию в mysql или нужно писать циклы на проверку с таймером. Куда вообще копать нужно?

Comment: mysql тут вообще не причем. Это база данных, она умеет принимать запросы и присылать ответы. на этом все. она ни как не может сама взаимодействовать с визуальным интерфейсом. Так что опишите в вопросе что за таблицы у вас такие, на каком языке программирования пишется интерфейс. Это надо решать его средствами

Comment: Данные берутся из программы quik. В ней реализована возможность передавать данные во внешние базы счерез ODBC
Я хочу получать эти данные в mysql и забирать их оттуда Python-ом для дальнейшего анализа. Вот для этого мне и нужно, чтобы в базе обновлялись данные, но не знаю с чего начать

Comment: Тогда только если в самой программе реализована такая возможность как автосохранение. быстрыг поиск в гугле показал что связь делают через LUA API в quik https://pypi.org/project/qlua/

Comment: Хотя как по мне информацию лучше бы у брокера прямо забирать, если конечно брокер API предоставляет

Comment: За ссылку отдельное спасибо и вцелом за помощь..